# passing a callback function to vue.js directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, vue.js

so i have a directive in vue.js which is pretty handy for having a single point that handles all request through out the app. you can view it at this gist

https://gist.github.com/jkirkby91-2/261fee5667efcf81648ab2a1a1c33c1b

but every form that uses this to process the request handles the response data completely different.

so is it possible i can pass a call back function to the ajax directive to handle the response data.

so for example i have a form that creates a new posts id like to pass a function that handles that response, i also have a search form that with the response data id like to handle to add markers to my map.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide an example of how you are using the `directive`?

I see that you have a parameter called "complete" in your gist. Do you intend to use it like this?

```js
<your-ajax-component v-bind:complete="some_callback_fn()"></your-ajax-component>
```

This is not the intended use for params. [params] is only for passing data to a child component.

You should use [Custom Events](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) to pass data from your child component to parent. The button counter (with two buttons and a main counter) is a great example.

Similarly, you can use `$emit()` from your ajax component as follows:

```js
// your-ajax-component
export default {
    methods: {
        doSomething: function (e) {
            this.$http.post("/api/some-url", {data}).then(response => {
                // your http action is done
                // now use $emit to communicate back to parent component
                this.$emit("ajax-complete", response)  // and you can pass the response data back
            }, error => {
                // your http action failed
                this.$emit("ajax-failed", error)  // parent component can handle this error from server
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Now from the template of your other components / routes, you can insert your-ajax-component and listen to events as follows:

```js
<your-ajax-component v-on:ajax-complete="some_callback" v-on:ajax-failed="error_callback"></your-ajax-component>
```

**Note:** `directives` serve a very different purpose. It is for getting access to DOM element, so that you can do something like focusing the element - put the cursor into a text box.

The documentation for [Custom Directives](https://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html) provides examples that are related only to DOM manipulation, and not parent-child communications.

Comment: ok maybe i missunderstood what directives where used for, il try this method and see how i get on

Comment: If you want an example for `$emit` from child component to parent, you can check out the jsFiddle in the answer for this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181133/delete-a-vue-child-component

Comment: Directives are a very different thing in Vue. I learnt a lot recently when answering this question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/40178466/654825 - in which you can check out the fiddle if you are interested.