# Drawing onto a canvas with vue.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, vue.js

I don't think this is necessarily a Vue based issue, but I'm running into some trouble.

I'd like to write to the canvas a Vue variable. If I remove vue, my initial code works fine, however if I add Vue the canvas doesn't actually start up.

Here is my code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.font="20px Georgia";
ctx.fillText("Hello World!",10,50);

var v = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    'exampleContent': 'This is TEXT'
  },
  watch: {
    exampleContent: function(val, oldVal) {
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.font="20px Georgia";
      ctx.fillText(this.exampleContent,10,50);
    }
  }
});
```

If I comment out `/* var v = new Vue({ ...` the initial bit works. If I log the value of `exampleContent` in the watcher that also works. But something about the canvas isn't working.

Demo to play with:
http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/EgGbgR?editors=1010

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please check this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/r4mbh6nu/

**EDIT:** updated with dynamic text: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/r4mbh6nu/1/

In the above example, I am able to write into canvas, and also ensure that the `input` text goes into `span` as you would expect, all using Vue.js

Coming back to your example, the HTML is:

```html
<div id="app">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    <input type="text" v-model="exampleContent" />
    <span>{{ exampleContent }}</span>
</div>
```

Vue.js reads the elements inside `#app` and keeps it as the template for your *Vue app*. So your `canvas`, `input` and `span` elements will now be re-rendered by Vue.js when it constructs the DOM.

During this process, your original canvas text - the one you set before initiating the Vue application gets lost.

There is no clear way to solve this issue other than using a `directive`, as in my jsFiddle example. A Vue directive helps you capture the DOM element.

In my example, I define a Vue directive called `insert-message` which I use on canvas as `v-insert-message`. This allows me to capture the DOM element and then do the other steps: `getContext` and `fillText`. There is no `id` required, or no javascript code to `getElementById`.

One more thing - your canvas is just too large, and therefore you were not able to see your `input` and `span` elements. They were working normally in your example also!

**EDIT: example for directive bindings**

I just found a way to use directives and still write dynamic stuff into canvas.

Check the updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/r4mbh6nu/1/

Comment: For more info on directives, here is the link to docs - https://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html

Comment: Hi Mani, thanks so much for the answer. In your example, how could I trigger the directive on change/watcher to put the text on the canvas? Regardless, I moved the canvas outside of the app (exactly as you said) and that works great, so thanks for the help.

Comment: If you didn't want to go the `directive` route, you could abstract your canvas updates to a `method` that is triggered both on vue instance `mounted` and in your `watch`. http://codepen.io/itopizarro/pen/amPEEO?editors=1010

Comment: @ItoPizarro Thanks for pointing out this method. I didn't think of it as I generally prefer not to have `id`s in Vue templates, as it limits reuse of component. Nevertheless, your solution is what @Djave wants at this moment. Can you put it as a separate answer, so he may want to accept it? :-)

Comment: @Mani Will do, though I agree that the `directive` is the more scalable approach and share your opinion about reusability.

Comment: Great answer! Readers may find it useful to know that you can pass this into the binding and thereby have access to all the properties of the app including computed ones, should you need do. e.g. here's a canvas that uses a computed property https://jsfiddle.net/r4mbh6nu/633/

Answer (score 19):

Here's an easy way that works with Vuejs 2:

1. Add the canvas to you template with a reference attribute:

   `ref="myCanvas"`
2. You can then access it anywhere inside your component using

   var canvas = this.$refs.myCanvas

Comment: For further clarification, this just means to add `ref="myCanvas"` to the `<canvas>` HTML tag within your template, as follows: `<canvas ref="myCanvas">`.

Answer (score 9):

As detailed in [@Mani's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40178466/5796134), Vue removes and re-renders the DOM element that a Vue instance is invoked upon.

If you abstract your canvas updating into a Vue instance `method`, you can trigger it at the `mounted` lifecycle hook (to get the initial value of `exampleContent`), the re-invoke it in your `watch` when `exampleContent` changes.

```js
var v = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    'exampleContent': 'This is TEXT'
  },
  methods: {
    updateCanvas: function (){
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
          ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.font="20px Georgia";
      ctx.fillText(this.exampleContent,10,50);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    exampleContent: function(val, oldVal) {
      this.updateCanvas();
    }
  },
  mounted: function (){
    this.updateCanvas();
  }
});
```

```css
canvas{
  background:red;
  width:800px;
  height:600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
  <input type="text" v-model="exampleContent" />
  <span>{{ exampleContent }}</span>
</div>
```

The preceding SO Code Snippet was created from forked version of OP's [CodePen](http://codepen.io/itopizarro/pen/amPEEO?editors=0100)

Comment: I just found a way to use binding with directives, and updated my answer. Check out how it works with directives: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/r4mbh6nu/1/ :-)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been viewed a few times, and I've used canvases and Vue thousands of times since I first asked it. This is the best option I have found in practise.

Give the canvas a `ref` as mentioned by a few people:

```
<div id="app">
  <canvas width="800" height="600" ref="nameOfCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Set the `context` of the canvas in the mounted function:

```
mounted(){
  this.canvas = this.$refs.nameOfCanvas;
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.render();
}
```

<sup>There is no need to put ctx in the `data` object unless you want to watch it.</sup>

That's it. From there, a `render` method can be created and reference data in your component...

```
render(){
  this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
}
```

You can also set up a `requestAnimationFrame` loop within this method like so:

```
render(){
  this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
  requestAnimationFrame(this.render);
}
```

Full demo / starter:
https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/gOROpqQ