# Vue.js component for Chart.js - strange issue on AJAX reload

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I have a Vue.js 2.0 component that's providing a Chart.js 2.0 bar chart with dynamic reloading of data with a filter select box.

After adding in click events to the chart data sets I've run into an issue when reloading data with the filter.  When the page first loads, I can click on each data set and log the information to the console.  After I select a filter from the select box and the data sets reload via AJAX, I get really sporadic results when clicking the data sets.  Most of the time after reloading I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_index' of undefined` but sometimes I will get between 2-4 data sets logged to the console, all but one of them no longer present in the current view.  My component code is below.  How can I fix the click events after reloading the chart data?  Any help is appreciated.

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';

export default {
template: `
    <div v-bind:class="[chartDivSize]">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4 class="title">
                            {{ title }}
                        </h4>
                        <p class="category">{{ category }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div v-if="isManager" class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                        <h4 class="title pull-right">Filter by Team</h4>
                        <select v-model="selectedFilter" @change="reload" class="form-control selectpicker">
                            <option v-for="filter in filters">{{ filter }}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <canvas v-bind:id="chartId" style="height: 352px; width: 704px;" width="1408" height="704"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <div class="legend">
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="stats">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>{{ stats }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
`,

props: ['ctx', 'chart', 'url', 'chartId', 'chartDivSize', 'title', 'category', 'stats', 'filters', 'isManager', 'selectedFilter', 'activePoints'],

ready() {
    this.load();
},

methods: {
    load() {
        this.fetchData().then(
            response => this.render(response.data)
        );
    },
    fetchData() {
        if(this.selectedFilter) {
            var resource = this.$resource(this.url);
            return resource.get({ filter: this.selectedFilter });
        } else {
            return this.$http.get(this.url);
        }
    },
    render(data) {
        this.title = data.title;
        this.category = data.category;
        this.stats = data.stats;
        this.filters = data.filters;
        this.filters.unshift('All');
        if(data.selectedFilter) {
            this.selectedFilter = data.selectedFilter;
        } else {
            this.selectedFilter = 'All';
        }
        this.isManager = data.isManager;

        this.ctx = $("#" + this.chartId);

        var chartData = {
            labels: data.labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: data.metric,
                    data: data.data,
                    backgroundColor: data.background_colors,
                    hoverBackgroundColor: data.hover_colors
                }]
        };

        this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
            type: "bar",
            data: chartData,
            options: {
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            fontStyle: "bold"
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            fontStyle: "bold"
                        }
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                }
            }
        });

        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.setChartClickHandler(this.ctx, this.chart);
        });

    },
    reload() {
        this.chart.destroy();
        this.load();
    },

    setChartClickHandler(ctx, chart) {
        ctx.on('click', evt => {
            var activePoints = chart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
            var label = chart.data.labels[activePoints[0]._index];
            var value = chart.data.datasets[activePoints[0]._datasetIndex].data[activePoints[0]._index];
            console.log(label,value);
        });
    },
},
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I have already posted an answer here, which points to some `Vue.js` usage issues. But I think the real problem is different, as explained below:

You `reload` function does the following:

```js
this.chart.destroy();
this.load();
this.setChartClickHandler(this.ctx, this.chart);
```

If you notice, the second line is `this.load()` which invokes `fetchData` asynchronously. When the `response` comes through, you render the chart using `this.render(response.data)`

Let's say your AJAX data takes 400 milli-seconds to come. So your chart will be rendered only after 400 milli-seconds. But your `this.chart` is already destroyed and will be recreated only after 400 milli-seconds inside your `render` function, using `new Chart(...)`.

But your `reload` function immediately proceeds to call `this.setChartClickHandler` with reference to `this.chart` which is already destroyed.

To fix this, you need to call `this.setChartClickHandler(..)` only after the `new Chart` is created inside the `render` function.

**EDIT: additional thoughts on the updated question**

You have another problem now: Your function is creating a new scope inside, and you have problem with binding of `this`

You currently have the following:

```js
this.$nextTick(function() {
    this.setChartClickHandler(this.ctx, this.chart);
});
```

Instead, you need to change it to:

```js
this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.setChartClickHandler(this.ctx, this.chart);
});
```

The arrow function ensures that you do not create a new scope inside, and your `this` inside the function is same as `this` of Vue component.

There is another function where you need to make the same change:

```js
ctx.on('click', function(evt) {
    var activePoints = chart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
    var label = chart.data.labels[activePoints[0]._index];
    var value = chart.data.datasets[activePoints[0]._datasetIndex].data[activePoints[0]._index];
    console.log(label,value);
});
```

The above lines need to be:

```js
ctx.on('click', evt => {
    var activePoints = chart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
    var label = chart.data.labels[activePoints[0]._index];
    var value = chart.data.datasets[activePoints[0]._datasetIndex].data[activePoints[0]._index];
    console.log(label,value);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Mani, thank you for the help.  I updated the component in my question based on your feedback, and although I'm getting the same results I figure I'm probably using the $nextTick incorrectly.  I'll explore the docs on bindings as well.  This is my first crack at Vue components.

Comment: Your error is `cannot read _index of undefined`. So you need to concentrate your debugging efforts around `activePoints[0]._index` which is inside your `setChartClickHandler` function. I think you need to provide a callback from your `load()` function after AJAX is done. After that, your `this.chart` will be defined and your `activePoints` will have something in it.

Comment: I just noticed your edited code in question. Now you have a problem with binding of `this`. You need to start using arrow functions everywhere. Please check my edited answer above.

Comment: Ok, I updated again with the arrow functions, that makes sense but I'm getting the same results.  The click events are really inconsistent after the reload.  If I click on the first bar 10 times, it will return undefined.  Then if I click on another bar it will return multiple data sets.  If I go back to the first bar, it will start returning data sets, or not.  It's all over the place.  I was thinking that when setChartClickHandler() is called on nextTick(), all the activePoints would be re-initialized with the fresh data, but it does seem to contain data from the previous chart.

Comment: I am not able to find anything else that is missing in code, it looks ok to me. You need to look at the data returned from AJAX and the chart APIs. Can you use [Vue devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) to check the data objects in component?

Comment: Yeah, I've checked the AJAX data and the Vue devtools chart structure and they're correct.  Not quite sure why the click handler is not behaving.  Thanks for taking the time to check this out.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `{{...}}` (mustaches) for binding your classes and IDs. VueJS does not allow you to do that. Instead you need to use v-bind as explained below:

The first line in your template is currently:

```html
<div class="{{ chartDivSize }}">
```

You need to change it to:

```html
<div v-bind:class="[chartDivSize]">
```

Ref: https://vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Most importantly, your canvas ID is probably not getting binded properly in your component. Currently you have:

```html
<canvas id="{{ chartId }}" style="height: 352px; width: 704px;" width="1408" height="704"></canvas>
```

It needs to be:

```html
<canvas v-bind:id="chartId" style="height: 352px; width: 704px;" width="1408" height="704"></canvas>
```

Ref: https://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

Instead of `v-bind:class` and `v-bind:id`, you may also use shorthand format like `:class` or `:id`, as specified in [the API docs for v-bind](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-bind).

You may still have issues after the above. VueJS renders the DOM, but your canvas may not be available instantaneously. You need to wait for a slight delay before the canvas with that ID becomes available in DOM. For that, you may use `Vue.nextTick()`, or simply `this.$nextTick()` before calling your **chart.js** APIs.

Reference for `Vue.nextTick()`: http://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-nextTick

**Edit: Additional Reference**

The above code should technically work - it should give you a canvas element with the ID specified. And in the `nextTick()`, you should be able to get that `<canvas>` and draw stuff into it.

If it does not work for any reason, you may need to capture the `<canvas>` element using directives. Here is a recent answer in Stackoverflow (that I posted few days ago), which has a jsFiddle example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40178466/654825

In the jsFiddle example for that answer, I have captured the `<canvas>` element without using the `id` parameter. Reason: A component is meant to be reused in multiple places, and therefore having a fixed `id` may defeat that purpose. As seen in that example, you may attempt to capture the `<canvas>` element directly using directives, which makes your component fully reusable.

Direct reference to that jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/r4mbh6nu/

Comment: My above answer points to few `Vue.js` usage issues, but the real problem seems to be something else. I have posted another answer here, please check it out.