# Delete a Vue child component

Tags: vue.js

I'm really stuck on this one.I have created a Vue (2.0) component that is made up of child components, it's all being Webpacked etc. For example, this is the parent:

```
<div>

    <h1>This is just a title for lulz</h1>

    <rowcomponent v-for="row in rows" :row-data="row"></rowcomponent>

</div>
```

which has a prop of `rows` passed to it which looks something like this:

```
rows: [{ sometext: "Foo"} , { sometext: "Bar" }]
```

So my row component looks like this:

```
<div>{{ this.sometext }} <button @click="deleteRow">Delete Row</button></div>
```

And I feel like it should be really easy to set a method on the `rowcomponent` that is something like this:

```
deleteRow() {
    this.delete();
}
```

Do I need to $emit something to the parent with the index of the row in it to remove it? It's driving me crazy. All the examples seem to suggest it would be easy to do, but not in the case where you have child components that want to delete themselves.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, the child component cannot delete itself. The reason is because the original data for `rows` is held in the parent component.

If the child component is allowed to delete itself, then there will be a mismatch between `rows` data on parent and the DOM view that got rendered.

Here is a simple jsFiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/4kyzkgLu/

As you can see, there is a parent component that holds the data array, and child component that sends events via `$emit` to delete itself. The parent listens for delete event using `v-on` as follows:

```
<row-component
    v-for="(row, index) in rows"
    :row-data="row"
    v-on:delete-row="deleteThisRow(index)">
</row-component>
```

The `index` property provided by `v-for` can be used to call the `deleteThisRow` method, when the `delete-row` event is received from the child component.

Comment: Just as a quick update on this one, I found that if you're dynamically adding rows, it fails and always removes the last one, however, if you do ````deleteThisRow(row) ```` and use ````this.rows.splice(this.rows.indexOf(row))```` it will be fine.

Comment: A correction to the above comment. It should be `this.rows.splice(this.rows.indexOf(row), 1)`

Comment: @BenHarvey could please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658348/creating-component-dynamically-always-removes-last-instance

Comment: This item is the one i find most counter-intuitive, but you managed to provide simple and elegant example. Thank you.

Comment: what if the child component does not have any data from the parent component?