# vue.js - right way to pass data from child to component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm a bit confused regarding the right way to pass data from the root instance to a component.

Let's say I have this root instance:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        foo: 'bar'
    },
});
```

Then I have a component in a separate .vue file:

```
<template>
    <div>I'm a component!</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            fooTest: function() {   
                console.log(this.$root.$data.foo);
            },
        },

        mounted() {
           this.fooTest();
        }
    }
</script>
```

This works fine. fooTest will get "bar" from the root instance data.

But is this the right way to do this? Or what is the best practice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not use `this.$root.$data`. It may work for now, but your debugging effort will be significantly higher when your app grows. It will be a nightmare when you are working with a team of developers on the same app.

Instead you should use proper parent-child communication. Here are the official docs for that:

From parent to child: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

From child to parent: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events

Here is another reference in StackOverflow to help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40181591/654825

The jsFiddle example in that reference answer has a case of parent component passing data to child, and child component passing events to parent.

In short, parent can pass data to child and listen to child events as follows:

```js
<child-component :data-from-parent="someValue" v-on:event-from-child="methodInParent"></child-component>
```

And child component can receive the above data from parent as follows:

```js
Vue.component('child-component', {
    props: ["dataFromParent"],
    ...
});
```

You can follow that jsFiddle example for a better understanding of how this communication works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Trying to do what you said:

http://kopy.io/saZ0K

How come I get undefined? The foo attribute is added to the component as it should - when inspecting the DOM. But I can't get it using this.foo ?

Comment: You are trying to use the ES6 module system within `<script>` tags. You need to use a build system like `vue-cli` to use module exports and imports. I don't know about kopy.io, but jsFiddle takes only javascript libs from a CDN. Can you check this example on how to define Vue component: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/4kyzkgLu/

Comment: I am compiling with webpack.

Comment: I am unable to follow your code in kopy.io, can you please put file names and the entire file contents for `parent.vue` and `child.vue`, so I can try it out locally at my end?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it related to a naming issue! I ussed :FooBar for the prop to pass - using all lowercase now, works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: At a high level, your code appears to be correct. You are passing `foo` from parent, and defining `foo` in `props` of child component. So technically it should work.

Comment: I tried to simplify my example - the real prop name I used was "bubbleColor", which I then tried to get in my component with this.bubbleColor. Realised I should use lowercase or change the name to bubble-color, to use bubbleColor :) my bad.

Comment: Easy to remember. data-from-parent, event-from-child :)