# Sending data to a non parent component in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to replicate the TODO MVC in VueJs.
(Please checkout this codepen : http://codepen.io/sankalpsingha/pen/gwymJg )
I have created a component called 'todo-list' with the following code :

```
Vue.component('todo-list',{
  template: '#todo-list',
  props: ['todo'],
  data: function() {
    return {
    // Let us set up a isEditing Boolean so that we can know if the user
    // will edit something and we need to change the state to reflect it.
      isEditing: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    enableEditing: function() {
      this.isEditing = true;
    },
    editTodo: function(todo) {
      // todo.todo = todo.todo.trim();
      this.isEditing = false;
    },
    removeTodo: function(todo) {
      //this.todos.$remove(todo); // --> This part is not working?
    }
  }
});
```

However, I have the data defined in the app instance :

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#todo-section',
  data: {
    newTodo: '',
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        todo: 'Go to the grocery',
        completed: false,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        todo: 'See the movie',
        completed: true,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        todo: 'Jack Reacher : Tom Cruise',
        completed: false,
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    addTodo: function() {
      // This will not allow any empty items to be added.
      if(this.newTodo.trim() == '') {
        return;
      }
      this.todos.push({
        todo: this.newTodo.trim(),
        completed: false,
      });
      this.newTodo = '';
    }
  }
});
```

I am not able to delete a single Todo from the list. My guess is that I have to send a emit message to the app instance and put up a listener there to delete the data from it? How do I delete the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried to delete by clicking the `x` button in your codePen example, I see the error: `this.$parent.todos.$remove` is not a function.

I have not looked deeply into your code. But attempting to access parent component methods using `this.$parent` is not a good idea. Reason: a component can be used anywhere, and assuming that it will have a $parent with a particular property or method is risky.

As you suggested in your question, you need to use `$emit` from the child component to delete the data.

There was another similar question here few days ago, for which I created a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/4kyzkgLu/

The child component has some code like:

```
<button @click="$emit('delete-row')">Delete</button>
```

This sends out an event to parent component. Parent component can subscribe to that event using `v-on` as seen in that jsFiddle example.

Here is that other question for reference: [Delete a Vue child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181133/delete-a-vue-child-component)

Comment: Btw he is using 2.0 and $remove, which is deprecated in Vue 2.

Comment: @Belmin thanks for pointing it out! I didn't know that it was from Vue 1.x, as I started learning Vue only after 2.0 release. So, `$remove` is supposed to remove an array item, so that we do not have to use `splice`?

Comment: Yeah, basically in Vue 1.0 $remove was just syntax sugar for array.splice - by coming Vue 2, it's deprecated so It's recommended to use array.splice for this stuff.

Comment: @mani it also has a good solution but I suggest you to use your methods in your parent.

Comment: @Med yes, I agree. But in this case, and also in my jsFiddle example for the other question, the delete button or the `x` button is actually on the child template. So, only the child can send an event upwards using `$emit`. As you rightly said, the delete method needs to be on parent, as the parent contains the array data. So, we need to have parent-child communication in this case.

Comment: yup... So my guess was right.. I had to emit and then put up a listener. I got it working. Thank you for the code example.

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to use your methods (DeleteTodo, EditTodo...) in your parent.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    newTodo: '',
    todos: [{
      id: 1,
      title: 'Go to the grocery',
      completed: false
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: 'See the movie',
      completed: true
    }, {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Jack Reacher : Tom Cruise',
      completed: false
    }]
  },

  methods: {
    addTodo: function() {
      this.todos.push({
        todo: this.newTodo.trim(),
        completed: false
      });
      this.newTodo = ''
    },

    deleteTodo: function(todo) {
      this.todos = this.todos.filter(function(i) {
        return i !== todo
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">{{ todo.title }}
      <button @click.prevent="deleteTodo(todo)">
        Delete
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already know this, however, this is not the answer to my question. Please check out the question again. However, it has been successfully been answered by @Mani.