# Vue 2 - Communication between components (sending and receiving data)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I working on app in Vue. I have problem with sending and receiving data between components. Already tried with `$dispatch/$broadcast`, `$emit/$on` but still now working. I want to send selected `active_club` from `ClubSelection.vue` to `vue_main.js`.

> Vue version: 2.0.3

Structure of my app:

1. vue_main - main Vue file

   1. HeaderElement.vue (**child of vue_main**)

      1. ClubSelection.vue (**child of HeaderElement**)

Need to send active_club from ClubSelection to vue_main.

> ClubSelection.vue

```
    <script>

    export default{
        props: [
            'club', 'title'
        ],
        created(){

            //Get club list
            this.$http.get('/api/clubs', function(data) {
                this.clubs = data;
                console.log(data);

                //read active club from parent
                this.selected = this.$parent.$parent.active_club;
            });

        },
        data(){
            return{
                clubs: [],
                selected: null,
            }
        },
        watch: {
            selected: function(v) {
                this.club = v;

                //Post to database selected club
                this.$http.post('/api/clubs/' + v + '/active')

            },
            club: function(v) {
                this.selected = v;

                //Change active_club at parent (THIS NOT WORKING)
//              this.$emit('active_club', v);
//              this.$parent.active_club = v;
                club.$emit('active_club', v);

            },
        }

    }
</script>
```

> vue_main.js

```
    const app = new Vue({
    router,
    data() {
        return {
            user: [],
            active_club: null,
            ranking: null
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        var self = this;

        this.$http.get('/api/users/me', function(data) {
            this.user = data;
            self.active_club = data.active_club;

        })

    }


}).$mount('#app');

const club = new Vue();

//THIS NOT WORKING
club.$on('active_club', function (id) {

    alert(id)
    this.active_club = id;
});
```

Errors:

> Vue warn]: Error in watcher "club"  (found in component
>   )
>
> vue_main.js:16924 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: club is not
>   defined

I have tried many set ups, this is one of them. How to make this working?

Answer (score 0):

`$dispatch` and `$broadcast` are deprecated in [Vue 2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873).

In your case, what you need is communication between a parent component and child component. When a child `$emit`s an event, parent can listen to it by providing a method in template markup itself, using `v-on:parentMethod()` as follows:

```html
<child-component v-on:child-event="handlerMethod"></child-component>
```

The above markup is done inside parent component's template. And the parent component needs to have that `handlerMethod` in its `methods`.

Here is a sample "parent-child communication" question on Stackoverflow, which has a jsFiddle example also: [Delete a Vue child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181133/delete-a-vue-child-component)

You may use the above answer as reference to implement `$emit` in your app.

**Edit: Additional Notes**

I forgot to mention the note about three level hierarchy you have. In your app, you have the following hierarchy:

parent: vue_main

child 1: HeaderElement

child 1.1: ClubSelection

For sending events from ClubSelection to vue_main, you may either use [non parent-child communication method](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) or you can relay the event using the intermediate HeaderElement.

Here is how the event relay can work:

- Step 1: ClubSelection sends a `$emit`, which is received by HeaderElement using `v-on`.
- Step 2: The `handlerMethod` in HeaderElement does a `this.$emit`, which can be received by your main template using another `v-on`.

While the above may look a bit convoluted, it is much more efficient than broadcasting to every single component in the app, as it is generally done in Angualr 1.x or other frameworks.

Comment: If you have two unrelated components (not parent-child), then you can use [Non Parent-Child Communication](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) as described in the docs.