# Vue 2 and child component events with multiple components

Tags: events, vue.js, vue-component

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280345/vue-2-communication-between-components-sending-and-receiving-data) question / answer, and whilst that works when the parent contains a specific component, in my scenario the parent contains this:

```
<component :is="currentView"></component>
```

and the value of `currentView` determines which component is 'loaded' at any particular time. So, using `v-on:event="handler"` in the component tag here means *all* child components must use the same event name :(. Is it possible in the `created()` function of the parent to set up specific handlers which will be called regardless of which component is currently 'in view', and when they each might send different events? For example, I have a login component which sends a 'login' event, and a data view component which sends an 'update' event. In the parent, I want something like this:

```
this.$on('login', doLogin)
this.$on('update', doUpdate)
```

However, that's listening to events *from itself*, not its children. I also tried giving the component a ref:

```
<component ref="main" :is="currentView"></component>
```

and using `this.$refs.main.$on('login', doLogin)`, but the `$refs` object isn't created until the initial render, so that *can't* go in the `mounted()` method (too early), and in the `updated()` method it will be repeatedly called which I'm sure isn't a good idea...

Answer (score 2):

you could set a global event and then pass the name of the action as a part of the payload, i.e

```js
const Login = {
  template: `<h1>Login</h1>`,
  mounted() {

    this.$emit('global-event', {
      action: 'login',
      data: {
        user: 'foo',
      },
    })

  },
}

const Update = {
  template: `<h1>Update</h1>`,
  mounted() {

    this.$emit('global-event', {
      action: 'update',
      data: {
        user: 'foo bar',
      },
    })

  },
}


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    called: {
      update: 0,
      login: 0,
    },
    currentView: 'login',
  },
  components: {
    Login,
    Update,
  },
  methods: {
    
    // within doSomething you would process the various events based on their payload.action
    doSomething (payload) {
      
      this.called[payload.action]++
      
    },
      
    toggleView () {
      
      this.currentView = this.currentView === 'login' ? 'update' : 'login'
      
    },
  
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component @global-event="doSomething" :is="currentView"></component>
  <button @click="toggleView">toggle view</button>
  <pre>{{ called }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm meant in the question by "all child components must use the same event name". I don't really like the single handler approach to be honest - more complicated to maintain. But see my answer below for what I think is a better alternative when you have control over all the child components.

Answer (score 1):

Gah! After spending ages searching, finding nothing, then posting here, I of course immediately stumble on the answer.

But this only applies *if* you have control over the child components (I'm building all of them). In the child, you simply:

```
this.$parent.$emit('login', {some: 'data'})
```

And then set up the event listeners with `this.$on('login', doLogin)` in the parent as normal in the `created()` method.

I'm sure there will be a scenario where I'm using a third party component that simply calls `this.$emit()`, and at the moment, I can't see any alternative to `v-on:eventName="handler"` in the parent.

Comment: it's an option but generally not recommended to fire events / set params on other vm's. If you can avoid it then it allows you to decouple your components: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events

Comment: I agree - but if my component specifies a set of events it will create, it seems there's little difference between fire and forget on the parent (which can choose to ignore them), and a parent explicitly listening for them on a child. And, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this without v-on, which in my case couples _all_ my components to each other, as they have to use the same event name!