# how can component delete itself in Vue 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

as title, how can I do that

from offical documentation just tell us that $delete can use argument 'object' and 'key'

but I want delete a component by itself like this

```
this.$delete(this)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, you will not be able to delete a component directly. The parent component will have to use `v-if` to remove the child component from the DOM.

Ref: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-if

Quoted from docs:

> Conditionally render the element based on the truthy-ness of the expression value. The element and its contained directives / components are destroyed and re-constructed during toggles.

If the child component is created as part of some data object on parent, you will have to send an event to parent via `$emit`, modify (or remove) the data and the child component will go away on its own. There was another question on this recently: [Delete a Vue child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181133/delete-a-vue-child-component)

Comment: That only applies if we are talking about a component that does have a parent component. But for root components created manually from js using `new Vue()` I'll assume [@bendytree's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55384005/2750743) is the way to go.

Answer (score 70):

I couldn't find instructions on completely removing a Vue instance, so here's what I wound up with:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  methods: {
    close () {
      // destroy the vue listeners, etc
      this.$destroy();

      // remove the element from the DOM
      this.$el.parentNode.removeChild(this.$el);
    }
  }
};
```

Vue 3 is basically the same, but you'd use `root` from the context argument:

```js
export default {
  setup(props, { root }){
    const close = () => {
      root.$destroy();
      root.$el.parentNode.removeChild(root.$el);
    };
    return { close };
  }
}
```

In both Vue 2 and Vue 3 you can use the instance you created:

```js
const instance = new Vue({ ... });
...
instance.$destroy();
instance.$el.parentNode.removeChild(instance.$el);
```

Comment: To remove DOM element, I did this and it works just fine: root.$el.remove(root.$el); No need the "parentNode" and the "Child" (saved space). Tested on FF/Chrome/Safari

Comment: How could I implement `this.$delete(object, key)` ?

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [beforeDestroy](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy) method on the component and make it remove itself from the DOM.

```
beforeDestroy () {
  this.$root.$el.parentNode.removeChild(this.$root.$el)
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. In my case though using your code does not work. I had to use this:
`beforeDestroy () {
  this.$el.parentNode.removeChild(this.$el)
},`
Could you maybe give me a hint why you used `$root` over the code proposed by @bendytree?

Comment: It would depend on the architecture of your application, I think now off the top of my head you would need to use `$root` if it's the only component on the page but if it's a nested component then you wont want to use `$root`. The more important bit is using the `beforeDestroy` which will trigger just before the component is naturally destroyed

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to re-render the component entirely you could bind a changing `key` value to the component `<MyComponent v-bind:key="some.changing.falue.from.a.viewmodel"/>`

So as the `key` value changes Vue will destroy and re-render your component.

Taken from [here](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/)