# Leaflet.js + Vue.js - Memory Leak when Navigating between Pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory-leaks, leaflet, vue-router

I'm trying to make a Vue.js application which includes a number of Leaflet maps.

The following jsfiddle is an example of the App I am trying to create:

https://jsfiddle.net/RayLa/vr2b6ad7/126/

The specific map component section is shown below:

```
const MapComponent = {
  template: '<div id="map">About</div>',
  mounted(){
    let map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 8);
    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
    
    fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinjc/UK-GeoJSON/master/json/administrative/gb/lad.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        L.geoJSON(data).addTo(map);
      })
  }
};
```

The app contains two pages, a "Home" page and a "Map" page.  The "Map" page contains a leaflet map. The App looks like below:

[image]

The problem is when I navigate from the "Map" page to the "Home" page and back again, there seems to be a large memory leak. From the chrome developer tools under the "Memory" tab, the amount of memory the App is using at the start is shown below (73.8MB):

[image]

Once I click from the "Home" page to the "Map" page several time, the amount of memory the app is using is shown below (739MB):

[image]

If I continue to click between the two pages, the app will eventually crash as it is out of memory.
I can't seem to find out what is the cause of this memory leak.

How do I unmount the component so all the related data is cleared from memory?

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? I'm not sure if this is something to do with Vue.js of Leaflet.js.

Comment: Every time the component gets mounted you create a new Component over and over again. While the old compoment with all informations is held in memory, that causes the high memory usage. By adding a simple `console.log(this)` at the end of your mounted() routine it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ1wH.png).

Comment: Thanks @Christopher. Is there a way to remove the old components from memory when a new one is created or I navigate away?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I personally don't know how. But there are a lot of related questions out there like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114956/leaflet-how-do-you-use-removelayer) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445125/how-can-component-delete-itself-in-vue-2-0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a vue expert, but I'm pretty sure the problem is that you are not destroying the leaflet map correctly. You have to call `map.remove()` (https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-remove), otherwise the DOM node holding the map will be kept in memory, even if your component is long gone.

The vue router should destroy your `MapComponent` once you navigate back to Home and you can use the `destroyed` lifecycle hook to remove the leaflet map with it. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wuo15b4L/

Comment: Thanks @mit. It's simple when you know how! I tried so many different things like removing the layers, or deleting the underlying data. Also, I assumed the data would get overwritten as it's using the same variable names. But, I guess not. Some other libraries I'm using don't have a handy `remove()` method, so I will have to figure out how to deal with these. I will award the bounty when it becomes available to me :) Thanks again

Comment: No problem at all.
React is going to create / destroy the component every time you navigate to / away from it, so there is no use in trying to overwrite variables within the component (think instance variables from object oriented programming). You are going to have a different instance of the component every time.
It is mostly libraries that manipulate DOM nodes and attach listeners to them which can cause memory leaks. And they generally have a corresponding `off()` function to their `on($event)` function, so if your other libraries do not fall under that category you might be fine. :)