# In Vue 2 after passing props v-for does not get updated after items are removed

Tags: vue.js, laravel-blade, vue-component

If I pass an array of objects using props in Vue 2 and on this array I use the v-for directive, view does not get updated if one of the array elements get removed.

This seems to work only if the v-for elements are declared as data, but my component needs to receive props...

In the example below you can see that the elements in the `services` array are indeed removed, but the v-for isn't triggered.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing here something wrong...

```js
Vue.component('location-service-list', {
  props: ['services'],
  template: '<div>{{ services }}<div v-for="(service, index) in services">{{ service.id }} - {{ service.name }} <a @click.prevent="remove(index)">remove</a></div></div>',
  methods: {
    remove(index) {
        this.services.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(this.services);
      },
  }
});

const app = window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#admin-app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.8/vue.js"></script>

<div id="admin-app">
  <location-service-list :services='[{"id":1,"name":"Test 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test 2"}]'></location-service-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining your servicesList inside the root component as follows:

```js
const app = window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#admin-app',
    data: {
        servicesList: [{"id":1,"name":"Test 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test 2"}]
    }
});
```

And your template as:

```html
<div id="admin-app">
    <location-service-list :services='servicesList'></location-service-list>
</div>
```

Now it will work alright without any issues. It was not working earlier because you passed it as a constant / immutable object (JSON string in the parent template which always evaluates to the same value whenever the parent template re-renders).

Technically you are not supposed to change objects passed via props in the child component. If you do the same to a string value that is passed via `props`, you will get an error message like:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly...

To process this **remove** action from parent component, you may refer to the answer under this question: [Delete a Vue child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181133/delete-a-vue-child-component)

The jsFiddle in that answer provides a way to send an event from child component to parent component, so that the appropriate child component can be deleted.