# In vue2 v-for nested component props aren't updated after element is removed in parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

For my app I'm using two Vue components. One that renders a list of "days" and one that renders for each "day" the list of "locations". So for example "day 1" can have the locations "Berlin", "London", "New York".

Everything gets rendered ok but after removing the "Day 1" from the list of days the view isn't rendered corrected. This is what happens:

1. The title of the day that was removed is replaced -> Correct
2. The content of the day that was removed isn't replaced -> Not correct

```js
Vue.component('day-list', {
  props: ['days'],
  template: '<div><div v-for="(day, index) in dayItems">{{ day.name }} <a href="#" @click.prevent="remove(index)">Remove day</a><location-list :locations="day.locations"></location-list><br/></div></div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      dayItems: this.days
    }
  },
  methods: {
    remove(index) {
      this.dayItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('location-list', {
  props: ['locations', 'services'],
  template: '<div><div v-for="(location, index) in locationItems">{{ location.name }} <a href="#" @click.prevent="remove(index)"</div></div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      locationItems: this.locations
    }
  },
  methods: {
    remove(index) {
      this.locationItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});

const app = window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: function() {
   return {
     days: [
        {
          name: 'Day 1',
          locations: [
            {name: 'Berlin'}, 
            {name: 'London'}, 
            {name: 'New York'}
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Day 2',
          locations: [
            {name: 'Moscow'}, 
            {name: 'Seul'}, 
            {name: 'Paris'}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  methods: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <day-list :days="days"></day-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use [Vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) if you are not already using it. It shows the problem clearly, as seen in the image below:

[image: Screenshot from Vue devtools]

As you can see above, your `day-list` component comprises of all the days you have in the original list, with locations listed out directly. You need one more component in between, call it `day-details`, which will render the info for a particular day. You may have the `location-list` inside the `day-details`.

Here is the updated code which works:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <day-list :days="days"></day-list>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('day-list', {
    props: ['days'],
    template: `
        <div>
            <day-details :day="day" v-for="(day, index) in days">
                <a href="#" @click.prevent="remove(index)">Remove day</a>
            </day-details>
        </div>`,
    methods: {
        remove(index) {
            this.days.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('day-details', {
    props: ['day'],
    template: `
        <div>
            {{ day.name }}
            <slot></slot>
            <location-list :locations="day.locations"></location-list>
            <br/>
        </div>`
});

Vue.component('location-list', {
    props: ['locations', 'services'],
    template: `
        <div>
            <div v-for="(location, index) in locations">
                {{ location.name }}
                <a href="#" @click.prevent="remove(index)">[x]</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        remove(index) {
            this.locations.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});

const app = window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: function() {
        return {
            days: [{
                name: 'Day 1',
                locations: [{
                    name: 'Berlin'
                }, {
                    name: 'London'
                }, {
                    name: 'New York'
                }]
            }, {
                name: 'Day 2',
                locations: [{
                    name: 'Moscow'
                }, {
                    name: 'Seul'
                }, {
                    name: 'Paris'
                }]
            }]
        }
    },

    methods: {}
});
```

One other thing - your template for `location-list` has an error - you are not closing the `<a>` element. You may use backtick operator to have multi-line templates as seen in the example above, to avoid template errors.

Also you are not supposed to change objects that are passed via `props`. It works here because you are passing objects which are passed by reference. But a string object getting modified in child component will result in this error:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly...

If you ever get this error, you may use event mechanism as explained in the answer for this question: [Delete a Vue child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181133/delete-a-vue-child-component)

Comment: Here is a working jsFiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/2gab0k3y/