# Creating Component Dynamically always removes last instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a `child` component and `parent` component. Parent component renders child component dynamically i.e. on demand and keeps the record in array. When a child component demands to be removed, it emits event and hence passes down its id to be identified in record. Though the record does get removed based on id but the last created instance is removed, always. Even if you click the first child, it is going to remove the last one only.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lahori/v0z02cna/) is the link that is identical to my situation but only in simple form.
I did research on SO and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181133/delete-a-vue-child-component) whose fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/4kyzkgLu/). So I did follow its pattern in another [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lahori/zaf5nzo6/) but result is no different.

I don't know whats the problem here... what I am doing wrong?

Update 1: Added Code

Update 2: Check first link if you want to skip below

**ChatPanel.vue**

```
 <template>
  <div class="chat-container">
    <div class="columns" style="justify-content: flex-end;">
      <div class="column is-3" style="order: 1;">
        <div class="chat-panel">
          <nav class="panel state" :class="[statusIn ? 'in' : 'out']">
            <p class="panel-heading">
              Arbab Nazar
              <span id="click-handle" @click="toggleState"></span>
            </p>
            <div class="panel-block">
              <p class="control has-icons-left">
                <input class="input is-small" type="text" placeholder="search">
                <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </span>
              </p>
            </div>
            <p class="panel-tabs">
              <a class="is-active">all</a>
              <a>Online</a>
              <a>Sleeping</a>
            </p>

            <chat-list/>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>

       <chat-window v-for="(window, index) in windows" 
                    :identity="index" 
                    v-on:remove-window="removeWindow(window)"
      /> 

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChatList from './ChatList'
import ChatWindow from './ChatWindow'

import Bus from '../Events/Bus.js'

export default {
  name: 'chatpanel',
  data () {
    return {
      statusIn: true,
      windows: [],
      id: Number
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    Bus.$on('new-window', (data)=> {
      this.windows.push((this.windows.length+1))
    })
  },
  methods: {
    toggleState(event) {
      event.stopPropagation()
      this.statusIn = !this.statusIn

    },
    removeWindow(window) {
      this.windows.splice(this.windows.indexOf(window),1)
    }
  },
  components: {
    ChatList,
    ChatWindow
  }
}
</script>
```

**ChatWindow.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="column is-2">
        <div class="chat-window-container" :class="{'reset': statusIn}">
            <div class="card state" :class="[statusIn ? 'in' : 'out']">
                <header class="card-header">
                    Ahmad Jan
                    <a class="delete" @click="$emit('remove-window')"></a>
                    <span id="click-handle" @click="toggleState"></span>
                </header>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <template v-for="message in messages">
                        <p>
                            {{ message }}
                        </p>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field has-addons">
                <div class="control is-expanded">
                    <input class="input" type="text" 
                            placeholder="Write something amazing..."
                            @keyup.enter="sendMessage" v-model="messageText"
                    >
                </div>
                <div class="control">
                    <a class="button is-primary" 
                        @click="sendMessage"
                        style="background:rgb(0, 184, 255)"
                    >
                    Send
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Bus from '../Events/Bus.js'

export default {
    props:['identity'],
    data() {
        return {
            messageText: '',
            messages: [],
            statusIn: true,
            id: ''
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.id = this.identity
    },
    methods: {
        sendMessage(event) {
            this.messages.push(this.messageText)
            this.messageText = ''
            console.log('msg', event.target.value)
            // this.messages
        },
        toggleState(event) {
            event.stopPropagation()
            this.statusIn = !this.statusIn

        },
        removeWindow(id) {
            console.log(`remove window with id ${id}`)
            Bus.$emit('remove-window', {id})
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**ChatList.vue**

```
<template>
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll;max-height: 17.5rem;">
        <template v-for="chat in chats">
            <chatter :user="chat"></chatter>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Chatter from './Chatter'

export default {
    props:{},
    data () {
        return {
            chats: [
                { name: 'Abdul Hameed', active: true  },
                { name: 'Ahmad Jan', active: false }, 
                { name: 'Murad Surkhab', active: false }, 
                { name: 'Angelo Mathews', active: false }, 
                { name: 'Hasan Ali', active: true }, 
                { name: 'Fakhar-ud-Din', active: true }, 
                { name: 'Sultan Usman', active: true }, 
                { name: 'Muad Saeed', active: false }, 
                { name: 'Saleem Yousaf', active: false }]
        }
    },
    components: {
        Chatter
    }
}
</script>
```

**Chatter.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a class="panel-block" :class="{'is-active':user.active }" @click="letsCaht">
            <div style="display: flex;">
                <p class="image is-24x24 chat-image" >
                    <img src="http://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png">
                </p>
                <p class="content">
                    {{user.name}}
                </p>
            </div>
            <span class="panel-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Bus from '../Events/Bus.js'

export default {
    props:['user'],
    methods: {
        letsCaht(event) {
            Bus.$emit('new-window', {user: this.user})
            console.log(`${this.user.name} is listening`)
        }
    },
    components: {}
}
</script>
```

Comment: how about some code?

Comment: @EliranMalka code is pretty complex so i added a link which resembles to my problem but is in simple form. here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/Lahori/v0z02cna/

Comment: that's actually part of the issue. if you provide the simplest, concise code snippet that causes the problem, you will have narrow it down to the problematic code (which you should do anyway)

Comment: @EliranMalka added Code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your deleting is working in the first fiddle but you're not seeing it correctly because your list is getting shorter if you're deleting one item. So it seems that always the last item is removed.

Also adding an `id` to your object helps Vue to render the `v-for` and you can add the key binding to id.

Please have a look at the demo below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/vbLrx4eg/3/).

**In your application code that you posted in your question:**

Is your remove handler called? You're emitting on bus but your listener is attached to this. Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zqptLse0/) so you're seeing the difference.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props:['index', 'data'],
    template: `
        <div>
            data# {{data}}
            <button @click="$emit('delete-me')">Delete</button>
        </div>`
})

Vue.component('parent', {
    template: `
        <div>
            Keep Adding new Instances 
            <button @click="newChild">New</button>
            <hr />
            <child v-for="(row, index) in children" :data="row" 
            v-on:delete-me="deleteThisRow(index)" :key="row.id"
            :index="index"
            ></child>
        </div>`,
        data() {
         return {
            id: 0,
           children:[]
          }
    },
    methods: {
     newChild() {
       this.children.push({
         id: this.id++,
         value: 'new child'
        })
      },
      deleteThisRow(index) {
         // console.log('index', index, this.children)
            this.children.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `
        <div>
          <parent />
            
        </div>
    `,
    
    methods: {
        
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @AWolf I noticed that too this morning and you are right I wasn't seeing it correctly. Actually the problem was not that respective window is not getting closed, the problem is when an instance is closed,it would pass down its data to next sibling which visually led me to believe that the window/instance is not being closed.

Comment: have a look here https://jsfiddle.net/Lahori/v0z02cna/3/. create 2/3 instances and then send a message in first instance & then delete it. the instance is removed but data is passed to next sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you add a new component, you should add a unique id for the new component.

this is work for me .

======================================================================

myradio.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
         <div>
             <label>{{inputVal}}</label>
         </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'myradio',
  data () {
    return{
      inputVal:new Date().getTime()//Get timestamp
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

mysurvey.vue

```
<template>
    <div>

        <div>
            <button v-on:click="addNewRadio">addNewRadio</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
         <div v-for="(item,index) in radioComponents" :key="item.myid">
             <li v-bind:is="item.myComponent"></li>
             <button v-on:click="delRadio(index)">delRadio</button>
             <hr>
         </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import myradio from '@/myComponent/myradio'

export default {
  name: 'mysurvey',
  components: {
    myradio
  },
  data () {
    return {
      radioComponents: [
        {
          myid:1,
          myComponent:myradio
        },
        {
          myid:2,
          myComponent:myradio
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addNewRadio:function(){
      let size=this.radioComponents.length+1;
      var json={
        myid:size,
        myComponent:myradio
      };
      this.radioComponents.push(json);
    },
    delRadio:function (index) {
      this.radioComponents.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

}
</script>
```