# VueJs - Deleting dynamically created child component always deletes the last one

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a parent component `customer` which have a child component `contact`
a customer can add as many components as he can now the problem is that whenever i remove any contact from the contact list it always removes the last contact.I am passing the contact which i need to remove and from the contacts array it is removing correctly but the component is not removing correctly ... please see the code for detail ... add some contacts and when you remove any of the contact, the last one will be deleted.
what's wrong here or what am i missing ?
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/amshehzad/93ebnfj5) is my code.
I have found very similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658348/creating-component-dynamically-always-removes-last-instance) and tried to do the same but it doesn't working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having same issue, after 3 days of research here is how i solved this issue ... the problem was that a unique key should be used with for loop which vue uses as reference for updating correct data in the DOM so i created another array and whenever a new component is created the id for that component is generated and get stored in it.
On add component:

```
addComponent(component) {
    this.components[component].push({id: this.id++})
},
```

and in the for loop:

```
<template v-for="(contact, index) in components.contact">
     <create-contact :count="index" @component-dispatched="catchComponent($event, 'contact')"  
          :key="contact.id" @component-removed="removeComponent($event, 'contact', index)">
     </create-contact>
</template>
```

Please see the fiddles for better understanding.

- [code with the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/amshehzad/93ebnfj5/47/)
- [updated code with solution](https://jsfiddle.net/amshehzad/93ebnfj5/49/)

Answer (score 0):

You should select the entire list as an array then select the first one like: 
const list = document.getElementById('someID');
// then you can do
    `list[0] // call Jquery on this element to remove it`